# How to build Terminal View in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity

I am trying to build a terminal view in Android,I am only using a single edit text.
I have reached till here [Terminal view Android (photo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsVwr.png)
Now, I am trying to shift the edit text from the first $ sign to the next $ sign, I didn't have any idea how to do this? can anyone please help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <com.jraska.console.Console
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursorstyle"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/cascadia"
            android:background="@null"

            />
    </com.jraska.console.Console>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you please explain your requirement properly, with some examples?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane actually i am trying to build a terminal app for Android just like termux Android app, but how to take the inputs since we know in Edit text we can take one input at a time but in termux we can continuously give the input after displaying results. So basically how to build the front end ? The XML part

Comment: @DanBaruch i tried but this didn't helped mei can you suggest the idea how to build the frontend part (XML one)?

Comment: Well, I don't work with recycle from any type so I don't know if there's a better approach, but what I'd do is make a TextView at the size of the screen and place a EditText with no background at the screen position where one would enter input. Upon pressing enter I'd move the EditText lower by the user input and command output

Comment: @DanBaruch Can you elaborate a little bit, like how the edit text will work again after displaying the result like in Linux when we enter any command it give some results and then agains blinks for input ..

Comment: Well, Lets say you want to write something like device $: as your terminal starting point. So you can calculate the length of that string and know it's length. You can then place your EditText at XY that will be after the "device $:" string. Give it focus and the marker will blink there. Once the users presses enter, you take the string, run the command and gets output. You then recalculate where the command output ends in the TextView and 1 line below that, you write "device $:" again, placing the EditText in the corresponding Y position. (since X remains the same)

Comment: Then again, I'm sure this is not the orthodox way of implementing it.

Comment: @DanBaruch yeah thanks, one last question if we implement like this we have to use a lot many Edit texts placing after every output is it Reliable?

Comment: No, you won't need a lot, you only need one. After the users presses enter you move all the text from the EditText to the TextView and relocate the same EditText (after clearing it's content) to it's new position

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thankyou so much @DanBaruch for your time. Sir can you please share your insta or discord or any other I'd where I can seek more help. If you are comfortable.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not using any social networks. Feel free to try though and when you encounter problems just create another post here, I'll answer if I see it :)

Comment: @DanBaruch no issues

Comment: Hey @DanBaruch Sorry disturbing you again, actually i was trying to relocate the edittext after every "$" but i am unable to do it, do you have any codes that will do it?.

Comment: That's no trouble at all. Are you unable to place the EditText in a specific X Y or are you unable to determine the relevant X Y needed to place the EditText at?

Comment: Both unable to place the edit text and determine the relevant xy position

Answer (score 0):

After trying the solution I provided in comments I've found a better approach.
You create a textView with your wanted terminal value (main_activity.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/current_line"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/current_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/user_input"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

mainActivity.java

```
private static final String TERMINAL_NAME = "terminal$:";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.current_line);
    tv.setText(TERMINAL_NAME);
```

And you override onKeyDown event as follows:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        char unicodeChar = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
        if(keyCode == 67){ // This is backspace
            et.setText(et.getText().subSequence(0, et.getText().length()-1));
        }
        else if(keyCode == 66){ // This is new line, here you need to process output and run the command
            
        }
        else {
            et.setText(et.getText() + "" + unicodeChar);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

This should get you started on applying more of your logic. This is just a mockup so don't fully copy paste it, take the relevant parts and of course, write it properly. I still don't know if this is the recommended approach but it does achieve the intended behavior.

Comment: Here et is edittext? and between **Thanks** so much @DanBaruch You helped me a lot

Comment: No, ended up using only textviews. and sure thing, if you can accept the answer if it helped you that'd be great :)